# Python variable and data structure scope

Tags: python, function, scope, breadth-first-search

```
if matrix[row][col] == 0:
            continue  # continue if it is a water cell

        matrix[row][col] = 0  # mark the cell visited by making it a water cell
```

This is a snippet from the program below. My question is how you are able to update countIslandsBFS()'s `matrix` from a function call to `visitIslandBFS()`

In general, I had thought only global variables could be changed with a function call. The visitIslandBFS() function they wrote returns nothing - so how is it possible to update the `matrix` passed in by countIslandBFS()?

```
from collections import deque


def countIslandsBFS(matrix):
    rows = len(matrix)
    cols = len(matrix[0])
    totalIslands = 0

    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            if (matrix[i][j] == 1):  # only if the cell is a land
                # we have found an island
                totalIslands += 1
                visitIslandBFS(matrix, i, j)
    return totalIslands


def visitIslandBFS(matrix,  x,  y):
    neighbors = deque([(x, y)])
    while neighbors:
        row, col = neighbors.popleft()

        if row < 0 or row >= len(matrix) or col < 0 or col >= len(matrix[0]):
            continue  # continue, if it is not a valid cell
        if matrix[row][col] == 0:
            continue  # continue if it is a water cell

        matrix[row][col] = 0  # mark the cell visited by making it a water cell

        # insert all neighboring cells to the queue for BFS
        neighbors.extend([(row + 1, col)])  # lower cell
        neighbors.extend([(row - 1, col)])  # upper cell
        neighbors.extend([(row, col + 1)])  # right cell
        neighbors.extend([(row, col - 1)])  # left cell


def main():
    print(countIslandsBFS([[0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [
          0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]))
    print(countIslandsBFS([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [
          0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]))


main()
```

Comment: `matrix` was passed as a parameter to the function; it's a mutable value, and got mutated.

Comment: Your `matrix` object is a 2D array (a list of lists). Lists are a mutable data type, which means if you pass a list from one function to another, then you are able to modify the internals of that list.

Comment: @jasonharper why is it a mutable value? I'm confused because I had originally thought functions could only affect variables within their scope, unless you return something to main as an update.

Comment: Oh okay, so I should research what kinds of variables and objects are mutable vs. immutable. thank you.

Comment: @yitivow219 *variables* are not values! Variables are *names that refer to values*. In Python, we generally call values *objects*. Objects may expose methods that *mutate their state*. Those objects are called "mutable".

Comment: @yitivow219 in Python, variables are *always mutable* (this isn't the case in every language!).  That is, `y = <something>; y = <someting else>` is always possible.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga wow, so you are saying that instead of passing a value into a function, I pass in a variable, in Python only, I have the ability to mutate value from the function I called the function in? I just have to turn stuff into variables to be able to mutate it?

Comment: @yitivow219 no. that is not what I'm saying. You dont "turn things into variables". The semantics of arguments to parameters in function calls in Python essentially is like *assigning to a local variable* (the *parameter*).

Comment: @yitivow219 maybe this article can help you - https://realpython.com/python-variables/